# Actionbarsherlock: Logo right - Buttons Left

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionbarSherlock for my application. 
Is there a possibility to change the arrangement of the items in the actionbar?

This is my default Actionbar:

[image: Default ActionBarSherlock]

and i want to have something like this:

[image]

I already tried to create a custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/titleColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
 </TextView>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout);
```

But all i get is something like this:

[image]

Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Where is your arrow image in your layout ?

Comment: Hi! what do you mean with the arrow image? If I use setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) appears an arrow on the left side of the "smiley". The smiley displays the Logo (i do not plan to use homeAsUp).

Comment: If its default button of the actionbar then AFAIK you can not change its position.

Comment: According to the posted example I can change the position of the Logo. The problem is that i do not know how to change the position of the buttons on the right (I set them up using onCreateOptionsMenu), but I can also add them "manually". Any examples?